# Updating DataTable with Django model objects

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django, datatables

I'm trying to update a dataTables data table in Django with an Ajax request to the Django database. The code I have to update the table in the HTML template is:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){

          var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": '/main/newrequests/'
          });

          setInterval(function(){
            table.ajax.reload();
          }, 20000)

      });
```

And the view for newrequests is:

```
def newrequests(request):
    requests = Request.objects.all()
    data = serializers.serialize('json', requests)


    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

When the table tries to update, there is an HTML 500 error and a DataTabels Ajax error. I think the issue is that the Ajax query isn't returning the right type of data - this is what the output looks like:

```
[{"model": "main.request", 
"pk": 1, 
"fields": {"room": "225", "request": "Where is the pool?", "done": false, "cannot": false, "time": 0, "loaded": false}}, 
{"model": "main.request", 
"pk": 2, 
"fields": {"room": "325", "request": "I'd like a pizza", "done": false, "cannot": false, "time": 0, "loaded": false}}], etc
```

I need to load the data from "fields" into the data table, which has corresponding headers of "Room", "Request", etc. How should I try to pass the data differently through Ajax in the newrequests view, or is there a way I can use mData from dataTables to access those values?

Thank you!

Comment: EDIT: use `return JsonResponse(data)` instead of a HttpResponse,
you will need to do `import from django.http import JsonResponse` as well
hope this helps!

Comment: Hi N. Ivanov, using the return JsonResponse(data) gives the same output and HTTP 500 error